# Cannot change/delete/commit/discard current branch

Tags: xcode, git, commit, git-branch

I created a local branch from a git repository that I am working on. I have done this many times but for some reason the branch was created and put a bunch of random junk all over my code. (like random text and arrows).

So I decided to wipe the branch and attempt to recreate it since I have never seen this before. I went to switch branches and it would not let me because "Working copy is modified." I attempted to commit changes but it said there were none to commit.

I then went on the terminal and tried to commit, discard, delete the branch, change branches. All of these went unnoticed (either 'nothing to commit/discard' or 'cannot delete/change unmodified current branch').

I am now stuck, not being able to change branches, commit the "changes", discard changes, or remove the branch. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the output of a `git status` on the command line?

Comment: # On branch <branch name>
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
# both modified:      Project/AppDelegate.m
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Did these "random texts and arrows" <<<<<<< look ======= like >>>>>>> this? If so, those were merge conflict markers...

Comment: Haha yup, but why would there be merge conflict arrows when creating a branch? There should not be anything to merge, right?

Comment: @Joel If you had uncommitted changes in your working directory, it's possible that those caused conflict with something you did, but you didn't really explain your sequence of `git checkout`/`git branch`/whatever, so it's hard to guess. It's also possible that someone did something earlier that resulted in those markers being placed, and then they committed the files as-is without actually resolving the conflicts...

Comment: Xcode git interfce sucks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git checkout master
git branch -D <branch you want to delete>
```

This will reset all the changes you currently have. And then will checkout the master branch to continue working on. And finally delete the branch you want to remove.

Comment: Wow! Thank you that worked! I did get this error message initially when I ran the git reset: "HEAD is now at 672f6a1 stupid." Any idea what it means?

Comment: @Joel It means your `HEAD` is currently pointing at the commit that has an SHA hash that starts with 672f6a1, and that the first line of the commit message on that commit contains the text "stupid." It might be a good idea to write better commit messages... just sayin'.